# Almost sure convergence of a sum of random variables

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics, random-variables

Suppose $(X_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is an i.i.d. sequence of rv's, where $X_i$ can take countably many values $\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ with probabilities $\{p_1,p_2\dots\}$, respectively. Let $p_{n,k}:= 1/n\sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{1}\{X_i=x_k\}$, for $k\in\mathbb{N}$. By the SLLN, we have $p_{n,k} \rightarrow p_k,\forall k$, almost surely, as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Here is my question: How do I show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|p_{n,k}-p_k|\rightarrow 0$, almost surely, as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

I was thinking of using Borell-Cantelli, but could not make it work. Any help is much appreciated. many thanks!

Comment: you can forget the probabilities.  If $\sum p_{n,k} = 1, \sum p_k = 1, p_{n,k} \rightarrow p_k$ then result follows. start by choosing $N$ so that $\sum_N^{\infty} p_k < \epsilon$

Comment: hi @mike: thanks for your comment, but I don't see (at least right away) why I can forget about the probabilities, and how to proceed from your suggestion? sorry, I'm probably confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fresh slate now.

It suffices to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_k |p_{k,n} - p_k| \leq \epsilon$ with probability $1$.

For some $N$ to choose later, decompose with triangle inequality $\sum_k |p_{k,n}-p_k| \leq \sum_{k\leq N} |p_{k,n}-p_k| + \sum_{k>N} p_{k,n} + \sum_{k>N} p_k$.

As a random variable, note that as $n \to \infty$, $\sum_{k>N} p_{k,n}$ converges a.s. to $r_N := \sum_{k>N} p_k$ by law of large numbers. Thus, we have that taking the limit in $n$,

$\lim_n \sum_k |p_{k,n} - p_k| \leq 2r_N$ with probability $1$ (here we applied law of large numbers on the finitely many terms as well). All that is left is to choose $N$ so that $2r_N  < \epsilon$, which can be done because $r_N \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: good answer! thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @s_2  It really surprised me how much trouble it is to go the other way... I am wondering if it is true that $p_{k,n} < Cp_k$ a.s for sufficiently large $n$...

Answer (score 0):

With probability $1$, you know that $p_{n,k} \to p_k$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $k$. Let us focus on this set (throw out the set of measure $0$ where we don't have convergence for all $k$. If you like, there are a countable number of such sets you need to throw out, so what you throw out has measure zero, thankfully). This problem no longer needs Borel Cantelli, it becomes regular analysis:

Let me ask the following: suppose you know $p_{n,k} \to p_k$, how can you show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_k |p_{n,k} - p_k| = 0$, with the additional assumption that $\sum_{k} p_{n,k} = \sum_{k} p_k = 1$? This is probably what mike means when he says forget about the probabilities (restrict your attention to the event that $p_{n,k} \to p_k$ for all $k$, as this occurs with probability $1$).

Comment: hi @Evan. thanks for your comment, but I'm still stuck (it should be simple, I feel, but I can't write it down properly). I get stuck with making the term $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty} p_{k,n}$ smaller than epsilon. Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: @Evan With the assumption that every $p_{n,k}$ is nonnegative.

Comment: @ Did: where does nonnegativity kick in here? thanks!

Comment: @s_2  limit sum exchange condition. But I think you can use Dominated Convergence Theorem, do you know it?

Comment: @Evan: thanks for the comment - I know DCT, but don't see (immediately) how it is applicable here? thanks for your help again, it is much appreciated.

Comment: @s_2  Ack. It isn't immediate, you are right. Will think on it. Perhaps Did can use the nonnegativity somehow.

Comment: @Evan: thanks, I would really appreciate any further help!

Comment: @s_2  One thing I thought of, for any fixed $N$, you can condense $\sum_{k>N} p_{k,n}$ into a single r.v. which converges to $\sum_{k>N} p_k$. Try playing with this idea (finitely many r.v. to deal with at a time now!)